# How to open view controller when popup is open - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using the `PopupDialog` library and have a button that when tapped loads a popup as shown in the code below:

```
// Create the dialog
let popup_around_me = AroundMePopUpViewController(nibName: "popup_around_me", bundle: nil)
popup_around_me.gh = self.getJobByLatitude(latitude: marker.position.latitude)
let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: popup_around_me, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .bounceDown, gestureDismissal: true)

present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
//print("marker.position.latitude: \(marker.position.latitude)")
```

Within my popup there are two buttons that open controllers.

Because I'm using a navigation bar, I think I should first close the popup and then open my controller. Without doing so my navigation bar is not loaded.

But I don't know whether this is the correct way to do it. 
If it's ok, how can I do(close popup and open controller)?

my button function:

```
 func cliclOnContent(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print("job id: \(self.gh.id)")

//below codes not load my navigation.
//        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentAJobViewController") as! ContentAJobViewController
//        vc.job_id = self.gh.id
//        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

       // let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentAJobViewController") as! ContentAJobViewController
//        controller.job_id = self.gh.id
//        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a reference (link) to the `PopupDialog` you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

Comment: Can you try to use `popup.tapButtonWithIndex` to close your popup?

Comment: If you are using navigation bar instead of segue, take a look at my answer below. I am assuming the lifecycle of the `PopupDialog` is similar to the `UIAlertController`. So you should not need to dismiss it manually. And through the button actions you shouldn't need the `UITapGestureRecognizer` tap recognizer, either.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

Actually you don't have to close it. It automatically close itself all you have to do is to call your View controller in respective button action.

I have a view controller and i made a call using segue like this in cancel button.

[image]

And my output is like this.by the way i just used their demo file for quick response.

[image]

Comment: How to close popup? how to detect popup is closed? Is there any function to detect it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the lifecycle of the above mentioned `PopupDialog`, but if it works like the `UIAlertController` it will dismiss automatically when one of the button actions are completed.

It looks like you are using the custom `PopupDialog` version. You should implement your buttons and button actions similar to this:

```
    func showCustomDialog(animated: Bool = true) {

        // Create a custom view controller
        let popup_around_me = AroundMePopUpViewController(nibName: "popup_around_me", bundle: nil)


        let popup_around_me = AroundMePopUpViewController(nibName: "popup_around_me", bundle: nil)
        popup_around_me.gh = self.getJobByLatitude(latitude: marker.position.latitude)
        // Create the dialog
        let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: popup_around_me, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .bounceDown, gestureDismissal: true)


        // Create first button
        let buttonOne = CancelButton(title: "CANCEL", height: 60) {
            // Do what you want when you cancel
        }

        // Create second button
        let buttonTwo = DefaultButton(title: "Open VC", height: 60) {
            self.gotoMyOtherViewController()
        }

        // Add buttons to dialog
        popup.addButtons([buttonOne, buttonTwo])

        // Present dialog
        present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Notice the call to `self.gotoMyOtherViewController()` within the "Open VC" button action this is where you would open the other VC since you are using `navigation bar` in stead of `segue`

```
func gotoMyOtherViewController(){
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentAJobViewController") as! ContentAJobViewController
    vc.job_id = self.gh.id        
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```